Issue to fetch guest token from API - access token to get successfully but issue to get on guest token
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://cogni-sparc.excelindia.com/api/v1/security/guest_token/', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[ConsoleApp2.GuestTokenRequest], Headers:
{
Origin: https://cogni-sparc.excelindia.com
Accept: application/json
Accept: text/plain
Accept: /
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Host: cogni-sparc.excelindia.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Encoding: deflate
Accept-Encoding: br
Accept-Encoding: zstd
Referer: https://cogni-sparc.excelindia.com/
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJee9.eyJmcmVzaCI6dHJ1ZSwiaWF0IjoxNzE3NTk0MjY5LCJqdGkiOiI3YTExOGFjYy00MzkxLTRiZDYtODVjNS1hNGFlMTc3ODhjYzYiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwic3ViIjoxLCJuYmYiOjE3MTc1OTQyNjksImNzcmYiOiIxZDBjYzJlZi1kOWFjLTQ2MswwwwezUtOGEyMi05NjMzZWI3MmQ3MjUiLCJleHAiOjE3MTc1OTUxNjl9.Nt1OHbXHsMjQOXDg_F7wVMEY_WExPblRL5ev5IMUiQo
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 158
}}
Code is i am using
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var guestTokenResponse = _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{_supersetApiUrl}/guest_token/", guestTokenBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (!guestTokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error: {guestTokenResponse.ReasonPhrase}");
            throw new Exception("Failed to get guest token");
        }

        var guestTokenResponseBody = await guestTokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return guestTokenResponseBody;

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var guestTokenResponse = _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{_supersetApiUrl}/guest_token/", guestTokenBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (!guestTokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error: {guestTokenResponse.ReasonPhrase}");
            throw new Exception("Failed to get guest token");
        }

        var guestTokenResponseBody = await guestTokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return guestTokenResponseBody;


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How to enable download chart option after  integrate superset in angular .
Properties enable for GUEST_ROLE_NAME = "Gamma"
